# Task.WhenAll - async a bit slower than sync

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.8

I'm very new to threads. I'm making about 50 OAuth2Client Http calls (implemented as Thread.Wait for simplicity).
Method pull_NN_async is not faster than pull_NN. After increasing number of iterations async version time lowered 10% below that of sync version. Still not as expected. Please guide me.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
internal static List<Task> tasks_list = new List<Task>();   
internal static void Main()
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(read_json_and_pull_NN_Async());
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(read_json_and_pull_NN_sync());
}    
internal static long read_json_and_pull_NN_Async()
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
           Task x = pull_NN_async();
           tasks_list.Add(x);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks_list);
    watch.Stop();
    return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
 }       

internal static long read_json_and_pull_NN_sync()
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
           pull_NN();
    }
    watch.Stop();
    return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
 }       

 private static async Task<int> pull_NN_async() 
 {
    await pull_NN();
    return 0;
 }

 private static Task pull_NN()
 {
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //simulated http OAuth2Client request
     return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: Guide you in what way?

Comment: And can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, there are no threads in the code you've posted.

Comment: How to run pull_NN parallelly?

Comment: You already are. You need to give us a [mcve] with both the async and the non-async versions showing that it isn't faster. Then we can help. Right now you just have broken code.

Comment: Like add 
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
(...)
watch.Stop();
really?

async version: pull_NN_async(). sync version: pull_NN()

Comment: Your `pull_NN` method returns `Task` so it also appears to be async. But since your code isn't runnable I cannot see what is your actual problem. I want to run your code and see that both the async and non-async is running in the same time. Then I can fix your code. Right now your code is not runnable and hence not fixable.

Comment: Can not do. Running MyOAuth2Client.sendRequest requires passwords and tones of code, but replacing it with a sleep should suffice. Replaced.

Comment: Seriously, I'm trying to help you, but you're not helping yourself. I want to be able to copy, paste, and run your code. `Thread.Sleep` is fine to replace `MyOAuth2Client.sendRequest`, but I want to run your code. Please take the time to make a working example of the problem you're facing with your code. You'll get an answer within 5 minutes of you posting that.

Comment: Some time ago I read a blogpost by someone moving from sync to async (lost the link, unfortunately). The first test showed the async version slower than the (highly optimized) sync version for a single request. However under increased load (lots of simultaneous requests) the sync version got slower and slower until the site crashed under the load, while the async version just kept to the same response time

Comment: @HansKeﬆing - I suspect that the OP is running all his code async by starting some fire-and-forget tasks, but until he gives us a [mcve] I can't be sure.

Comment: No, no fire-and-forget tasks is this part of program. After increasing number of iterations async version time lowered 10% below that of sync version. I guess that assures me threads work as expected. I'll be looking for bottlenecks somewhere else.

Comment: @krisu - I applaud your code changes in the question, but it's still not a [mcve]. I can't run it. It's full of syntax errors.

Comment: The method `private static async Task<int> pull_NN_async() ` returns a `Task<int>` but the code returns `null`. And `private static Task pull_NN()` returns `Task`, but the method return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fire and forget task and you have a poorly created async method.

Here's your code written properly:

```
public class Program
{
    internal static List<Task> tasks_list = new List<Task>();
    internal static async Task Main()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(await read_json_and_pull_NN_Async());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(read_json_and_pull_NN_sync());
    }
    internal static async Task<long> read_json_and_pull_NN_Async()
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Task x = pull_NN_async();
            tasks_list.Add(x);
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks_list);
        watch.Stop();
        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    internal static long read_json_and_pull_NN_sync()
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            pull_NN();
        }
        watch.Stop();
        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private static async Task pull_NN_async()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    }

    private static void pull_NN()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can not be done your way. You changed pull_NN() to void and in pull_NN_async() you changed await pull_NN() to await Task.Delay(). Please remember sleeping represents http calls implemented in pull_NN(), so if you change pull_NN() to void, you can't await it.

Comment: It made no sense having `pull_NN` return a `Task` - especially when you then returned `null`. And making `pull_NN_async` await a synchronous `pull_NN` that returns `null` also just doesn't work. It's all of these things that made your original code not work as expected. You need to do it my why or explain what cannot be done my way.

Comment: And calling `Task.WhenAll(tasks_list);` without the `await` (as you did in your code) makes it a fire-and-forget method.

Comment: OK, added await to Task.WhenAll(tasks_list);. Would making pull_NN return int instead of void do the trick?

Comment: @krisu - No, you need to implement it like I did.

Comment: As I said - can not be done your way, because pull_NN_async() calls pull_NN(). It's because pull_NN() calls dozens of methods (refreshing login tokens, logging to DB etc.) to finally make a http call. Should I change all of them to async methods? Or can I use a delagate with BeginInvoke (to have async method call a synch method)?

Comment: @krisu - Your `pull_NN()` must not return a `Task`. If they are you must change all of them. Your `pull_NN_aync()` could then, and only then, use `Task pull_NN_async() => Task.Run(() => pull_NN());`.

Comment: Task pull_NN_async() => Task.Run(() => pull_NN()); this works. Many thanks!

Comment: Wait. Something is wrong. Program finishes before the last thread finishes await Task.WhenAll(tasks_list); Why?

Comment: @krisu - In my code or yours?